# How could I change the style of a [input="range"] dynamically without jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, html, css, range

Actually, this is what I want:

http://danielstern.ca/range.css/?ref=css-tricks#/

In this case, when you are dragging the range thumb (in the red area), the range thumb of the top slider is changing (in the green area).

This is what I want: **when I drag a slider, its color/style get changed according to the position of my thumb**.

I don't know how they did it.

[image]

I found some jQuery slider(range) plugins but I'd like to keep the app simple.

What can I do?

What comes to my mind is to use JavaScript to set new `<style>` tags into the HTML code. But this way sounds very weird. Are there any better ways?

Comment: You can have different classes defined with different colors. And then when your range changes, you can check the value and add the required class that updates the color.

Comment: That would be a way but I need dynamic effect, which would consume hundreds of class names.

Answer (score 0):

**Vanilla JS**

I don't have the time to exactly reproduce what you want in Vanilla JS. I already test a similar features on this codepen : http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/bErqwQ

I will provide you the code below, you have here all parts you need to do what you want without any library/framework.

Basically, not attach the first range on an html element but on another range.

But, as you can see, it's not because you do not use a library you will kept a code simple.

```js
var Range = function(input, range, thumb, onChangeCallback) {
    var startElement,
        inputEvent = (!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE|Trident/g)) ? "input" : "change",
        inputScope = input.getAttribute("max") - input.getAttribute("min"),
        rangeScope = range.offsetWidth - thumb.offsetWidth,
        rangeOffset = range.getBoundingClientRect().left + document.body.scrollLeft,
        thumbHalfOffset = thumb.offsetWidth / 2,
        setValue = function (value) {
            if (value < thumbHalfOffset) {
                thumb.style.left = 0;
            } else if (value > rangeScope - thumbHalfOffset) {
                thumb.style.left = rangeScope + "px";
            } else {
                thumb.style.left = value - thumbHalfOffset + "px";
            }
            return Math.floor((value * inputScope) / rangeScope);
        }, 
        firstWayBinding = function (e) {
            var value = (rangeScope / inputScope) * e.target.value;
            setValue(value);
            onChangeCallback && onChangeCallback(e.target.value, value);
        },
        secondWayBinding = function (value) {
            input.value = value;
        },
        startMove = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var pageX = (e.touches && e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].pageX) || e.pageX,
                pageY = (e.touches && e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].pageY) || e.pageY,
                rangeValue = (pageX - rangeOffset < rangeScope) ? pageX - rangeOffset : rangeScope,
                inputValue;

            range.draggable = true;
            range.style.cursor = "move";
            startElement = document.elementFromPoint(pageX, pageY);
            inputValue = setValue(rangeValue);
            secondWayBinding(inputValue);
            onChangeCallback && onChangeCallback(inputValue, rangeValue);
        },
        endMove = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            range.draggable = false;
            range.style.cursor = "";
        },
        whileMove = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          
            console.log("Move !");
          
            var pageX = (e.touches && e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].pageX) || e.pageX,
                pageY = (e.touches && e.touches[0] && e.touches[0].pageY) || e.pageY,
                rangeValue = (pageX - rangeOffset < rangeScope) ? pageX - rangeOffset : rangeScope,
                inputValue;

            if (range.draggable) {
                inputValue = setValue(rangeValue);
                secondWayBinding(inputValue);
                onChangeCallback && onChangeCallback(inputValue, rangeValue);

                if (e.type === "touchmove" && startElement !== document.elementFromPoint(pageX, pageY)) {
                    endMove(e);
                }
            }
        },
        preventDefault = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } ; 

    input.addEventListener(inputEvent, firstWayBinding);
    range.addEventListener("touchstart", startMove);
    range.addEventListener("touchmove", whileMove);
    range.addEventListener("touchend", endMove);
    range.addEventListener("mousemove", whileMove);
    range.addEventListener("mousedown", startMove);
    range.addEventListener("mouseup", endMove);
    range.addEventListener("mouseleave", endMove);
    range.addEventListener("dragstart", preventDefault);
};

new Range(
    document.getElementsByClassName("real-range")[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName("range")[0], 
    document.getElementsByClassName("thumb")[0], 
    function(inputValue, rangeValue) {
        //console.log(inputValue);
        //console.log(rangeValue);
    }
);
```

```css
body {
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.range {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 12px;
  height: calc(100% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: move;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<input class="real-range" type="range" value="0" min="0" max="4">

<div class="range">
  <div class="slide"></div>
  <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

**Vue.js**

It's really simple with Vue.js.

```js
new Vue({
  el: ".example",
  data: {
    red: 255,
    green: 255,
    blue: 255,
    opacity: 100
  },
  computed: {
    all: function () {
      return (+this.red) + (+this.green) + (+this. blue);
    },
    color: function () {
      return "rgba(" + this.red + ", " + this.green + ", " + this. blue + ", " + (this.opacity / 100) + ")";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}
.sample {
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <div class="sample" v-bind:style="{ 'background-color': color }">
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Couleurs</p>
    <p>
      <input type="range" class="main--range" v-model="all" max="765" />
      <input type="text" class="main--input" v-bind:value="color" />
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="colors">
    <p>Principale</p>
    <div class="red">
      <p>
        Red
        <input type="range" class="red--range" 
               v-model="red" max="255" />
        <input type="text" class="red--input"
               v-model="red" />
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <p>
        Green
        <input type="range" class="green--range" 
               v-model="green" max="255" />
        <input type="text" class="green--input"
               v-model="green"  />
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <p>
        Blue
        <input type="range" class="blue--range" 
               v-model="blue" max="255" />
        <input type="text" class="blue--input"
               v-model="blue"  />
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="opacity">
      <p>
        Opacity
        <input type="range" class="opacity--range" 
               v-model="opacity" max="100" />
        <input type="text" class="opacity--input"
               v-model="opacity"  />
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the style of the slider changes according to the position.